# GridView.LayoutParams does not exist, Android code breaks

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm following along the HelloWorld tutorials for Android but when I do the GridView exercise (http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-gridview.html)

I found that if I comment out the line: imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));

Then everything works. I did some research and found that GridView.LayoutParams does not exist. Am I doing something wrong? Is the tutorial broken?

Answer (score 6):

> > I did some research and found that GridView.LayoutParams does not exist.

Where did you research? `GridView.LayoutParams` does exist. [`LayoutParams`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams.html) is a class inherited from the `ViewGroup` class, which is the super class of `GridView`.

**Edit:**

Just took a look and it seems that, as you said, `LayoutParams` are not accessible from `GridView`. Use `AbsListView.LayoutParams` instead.

Comment: the issue is why GridView.LayoutParams can be used on SDK 8?

Answer (score 6):

`GridView.LayoutParams` is actually `AbsListView.LayoutParams`, so you can safely use that instead.

Answer (score 0):

This should normally be no issue, but as you have one, you can replace `GridView.LayoutParam`
with `AbsListView.LayoutParam`, as `GridView` is a subclass of `AbsListView`.

Answer (score 0):

GridView is inherited from ViewGroup, ViewGroup which has the LayoutParams class. The tutorial is not broken, what error are you getting?

Comment: For some reason I was getting exceptions thrown yesterday, but I recompiled and it works today. Thanks for the help!